# redis/debian: where can I find the configuration file

Tags: redis, debian

Quick question: where can I find my redis configuration file? I'm running debian 10. I've installed redis with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install redis-server
```

I've found a config-file on the following location: `/etc/redis/redis.conf`, but changing this configuration file has no effect on redis, even if I restart my server.

When using the CONFIG SET/GET commands, I get other output. I want to change the bind address.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I'm finding out (with `info server`) that there is no config file loaded. When running the following command: `redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf`, I get the fatal error that the config-file can't be opened. But I can open the file with nano?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is due to a missing filesystem permission, with the user running Redis (named as *redis*, by default) not allowed to read/[write](https://superuser.com/questions/1393003/why-does-redis-need-write-permissions-for-redis-conf) the file `/etc/redis/redis.conf`.

Installing `redis-server` via apt should also configure redis to run as a systemd service, along with the proper filesystem permissions, so restarting your Redis service with `service redis restart` should also reload the modified configuration file. If that doesn't work, just make sure the user you are running Redis under has the correct filesystem permissions as mentioned above.